# Dlookup in Query criteria: slow

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query against 6 Oracle tables, all inner joins.
When I run it with condition
`WHERE tablex.MsgId > 13298690`, the answer is immediate.
When I run it with condition
`WHERE tablex.MsgId > Dlookup("ParamLong","tblParamSave","ParamName='SomeName'")`, it is taking 1 minute.
And of course, the Dlookup returns 13298690, so both queries are functionally identical.

Comment: My guess, it is evaluating the function for each and every row in the second case, whereas in the first case it is just doing an index look up.

Comment: Possible solution, evaluate the function and save the result into a variable and then use the variable for comparison.

Comment: I don't recommend using VBA functions inside queries. It would be better to use ADO or SQL Pass Through Queries once are having performance problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely and interestingly, 'strong typing' the criteria expression to:

```
WHERE tablex.MsgId > CLng(Dlookup(...))
```

restored the full speed of the query.